# Distance Between Locations Using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, cllocation

So I have a `Core Data` with an entity containing a longitude and latitude as `NSNumbers`. I want the `NSFetchRequest`'s `Predicate` to filter based on how far the object in the database's location is from my current location. This would require me to convert the stored coordinates to CLLocationDegrees and then put them in a `CLLocation` object. Finally, I can do the compare with the `CLLocation` `distanceFromLocation`.

I worded this as best as I can, does anyone have any ideas how I can do this with an `NSPredicate`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try block-based predicate:

```
CLLocationDistance maxDistance = 100.0;
CLLocation *currentLocation = ...;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id location, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation] <= maxDistance;
}];
```

Comment: Important to note that predicateWithBlock with Core Data is only supported for in-memory and atomic stores and _not_ for SQLite-based stores which is most likely what the OP using.